# Use Hibernate to serach two sql tables,How to fix it

Tags: hibernate

This is my HibernateDaoImpl which is for get valuse from Emp and Org tables such as ORG_ID,ORG_NAME,ID,ORG_ID,EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,CARD_NUM,
ORG_PAY,EMP_PAY.

How I can use java code to iterator them to check this valuses which is or is not what I want to get ?

```
public List<Emp> findByOrgId(String orgId) throws Exception {
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    String hql = "select o.orgId,o.orgName,e.empId,e.empName,e.cardNum,e.orgPay,e.empPay from Org o,Emp e where e.orgId=o.orgId and o.orgId=?";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setString(0,orgId);
    List list = query.list();
    return list;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query expects a parameter (a value for `o.orgId`), but you don't pass any.

The code should look like

```
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<Emp> empList = (List<Emp>) query.setInteger(orgId).list();
```

Looking at the query, it alwo looks like the Emp entity should have an association to an Org entity rather than to have its ID. I would also name the entities Employee and Organization. Your code would be much more readable than with these 3-letters names.